# wpf How to set xctk:ColorPicker default color

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit

EDIT: I actually managed to fix the problem, I was doing `Binding Value.Color` instead of `Binding Color`, which was previously set. Thanks for the help anyway!

I'm making a GUI that has a xctk:ColorPicker in xaml:

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <xctk:ColorPicker SelectedColor="{Binding Value.Color}"  Width="40"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Currently, the default color of the selector is Blue, I would like to change it to black. How do i accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

The color picker shows the default color from your binded property value

so in this case if your property Value.Color return blue then it will be blue

So by changing the property color to black would change it to black

but in case if you do not want to change the property value then you could make use of a placeholder property with default value of black and update the source when it changes

example for placeholder approach

```
<Grid Background="{Binding Value}">
    <xctk:ColorPicker SelectedColor="{Binding PlaceHolder}"  Width="40" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

view model

```cs
bool isDefault = true;
public Color PlaceHolder
{
    get
    {
        if (isDefault)
            return Colors.Black;

        return Value.Color;
    }
    set
    {
        Value.Color = value;
        isDefault = false;
    }
}

public SolidColorBrush Value { get; set; }
```

in above example I assumed Value of type `SolidColorBrush`, and I initialized it as `Value = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET 4, then you can change the `Background` colour of the selected row in the `GridView` by simply defining a few `Resource`s... just add these to your `GridView.Resources` collection:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Blue" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Blue" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
```